# Using bitwise on a large number in mysql

Tags: mysql, bit-manipulation

I have a need to store a provider name and the country(ies) they are able to provide services in. There are 92 counties. Rather than store up to 92 rows, I'd like to store 2^91 so if they provide only in county 1 and 2, I'd store 3.

The problem I'm having is the largest number is `2475880078570760549798248448`, which is way too big for the largest BigInt.

In the past when I've had smaller numbers of options I've been able to do something like....

```
SELECT * FROM tblWhatever WHERE my_col & 2;
```

If my_col had 2, 3, 6, etc. stored (anything with bit 2) it would be found.

I guess I'm not sure of 2 things... how to store AND how to query if stored in a way other than an INT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `BINARY(13)` as a datatype to store up to 94 bits.  But MySQL bitwise operators only support `BIGINT` which is 64 bits.

So if you want to use bitwise operators, you'd have to store your county bitfield in two `BIGINT` columns (or perhaps one `BIGINT` and one `INT`), and in application code work out which of the two columns to search.  That seems like it's awkward.

However, I'll point out a performance consideration: using bitwise operators for searching isn't very efficient.  You can't make use of an index to do the search, so every query is be forced to perform a table-scan.  As your data grows, this will become more and more costly.

It's the same problem as searching for a substring with `LIKE '%word%'`, or searching for all dates with a given day of the month.

So I'd suggest storing each county in a separate row after all.  You don't have to store 92 rows for each service provider -- you only have to store as many rows as the number of counties they service.  The absence of a row indicates no service in that county.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I was just reading on the indexing issue, so you may have a good point I hadn't realized. There's an added part that I left out for the sake of clarity where a provider may provide multiple services, so storing the provider ID, with each service ID in each county makes the table even bigger... I can at least index these though...

Comment: Yes, you may end up with a many-to-many table between services,  providers, and counties.  But with proper indexes, lots of sites use MySQL efficiently even with millions of rows in a table.